# Escaping bash variables before storing them in an apache hive database

Tags: bash, quoting, string, sql, apache-hive

I'm running a script file `sqoop_import_ATM.sh` and would like to store the logs in a `SQL` database.

First thing I did was to direct the logs into my own variable:

```
OUTPUT="$(/home/me/sqoop_insights_extract/./sqoop_import_ATM.sh 2>&1)"
```

This gets both `stdout` and `stderr`

Then I store this `OUTPUT` in a `SQL` database (this part doesn't work):

```
hive -e "INSERT INTO SCHEDULED_MIGRATION_LOGS VALUES ('$OUTPUT')"
```

Here is an example of the log that `OUTPUT` might hold:

```
rm: `transaction_detail_atm': No such file or directory Warning: /usr/iop/4.1.0.0/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail. Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation. 16/07/26 10:28:33 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6_IBM_20 SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J
```

To remove the harmful single quotes I tried using

```
$OUTPUT | sed "s/'/\ /g"
```

This seemed to have worked.

Now there's a problem with the line `[jar:file:/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]`

It starts checking my directory for this file or something

Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, I'm very new to bash.

Any idea how to simply post this log to my `SQL` database

**EDIT - Entire LOG**

```
rm: `transaction_detail_atm': No such file or directory Warning: /usr/iop/4.1.0.0/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail. Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation. 16/07/26 10:28:33 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6_IBM_20 SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] 16/07/26 10:28:33 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead. 16/07/26 10:28:33 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override 16/07/26 10:28:33 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc. 16/07/26 10:28:33 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time. 16/07/26 10:28:33 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000 16/07/26 10:28:33 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation 16/07/26 10:28:34 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select QueryResult.java sqoop_import_ALL.sh sqoop_import_ATM.sh sqoop_import_CC.sh sqoop_import_TD.sh sqoop_import_VD.sh testscript.sh transaction_detail.java transaction_detail_visa_debit.java from transaction_detail_atm where posted_dte = current_date-1 and (1 = 0) 16/07/26 10:28:35 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select QueryResult.java sqoop_import_ALL.sh sqoop_import_ATM.sh sqoop_import_CC.sh sqoop_import_TD.sh sqoop_import_VD.sh testscript.sh transaction_detail.java transaction_detail_visa_debit.java from transaction_detail_atm where posted_dte = current_date-1 and (1 = 0) 16/07/26 10:28:35 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/iop/4.1.0.0/hadoop Note: /tmp/sqoop-u28158/compile/5fe23466bd0c4860e3529366cde274b4/QueryResult.java uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 16/07/26 10:28:37 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-u28158/compile/5fe23466bd0c4860e3529366cde274b4/QueryResult.jar 16/07/26 10:28:37 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning query import. 16/07/26 10:28:38 INFO impl.TimelineClientImpl: Timeline service address: http://rhdtmomg1.mid.aib.pri:8188/ws/v1/timeline/ 16/07/26 10:28:38 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at rhdtmomg1.mid.aib.pri/10.30.39.1:8050 16/07/26 10:28:43 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation 16/07/26 10:28:44 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1 16/07/26 10:28:44 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1464347352640_0138 16/07/26 10:28:44 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1464347352640_0138 16/07/26 10:28:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://rhdtmomg1.mid.aib.pri:8088/proxy/application_1464347352640_0138/ 16/07/26 10:28:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1464347352640_0138 16/07/26 10:28:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1464347352640_0138 running in uber mode : false 16/07/26 10:28:49 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 0% reduce 0% 16/07/26 10:31:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: map 100% reduce 0% 16/07/26 10:31:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1464347352640_0138 completed successfully 16/07/26 10:31:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 30 File System Counters FILE: Number of bytes read=0 FILE: Number of bytes written=147903 FILE: Number of read operations=0 FILE: Number of large read operations=0 FILE: Number of write operations=0 HDFS: Number of bytes read=87 HDFS: Number of bytes written=2514798055 HDFS: Number of read operations=4 HDFS: Number of large read operations=0 HDFS: Number of write operations=2 Job Counters Launched map tasks=1 Other local map tasks=1 Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=149743 Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0 Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=149743 Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=149743 Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=306673664 Map-Reduce Framework Map input records=4073603 Map output records=4073603 Input split bytes=87 Spilled Records=0 Failed Shuffles=0 Merged Map outputs=0 GC time elapsed (ms)=2264 CPU time spent (ms)=127770 Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=368541696 Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=3798663168 Total committed heap usage (bytes)=331350016 File Input Format Counters Bytes Read=0 File Output Format Counters Bytes Written=2514798055 16/07/26 10:31:22 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 2.3421 GB in 164.7606 seconds (14.5563 MB/sec) 16/07/26 10:31:22 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 4073603 records. 16/07/26 10:31:22 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select QueryResult.java sqoop_import_ALL.sh sqoop_import_ATM.sh sqoop_import_CC.sh sqoop_import_TD.sh sqoop_import_VD.sh testscript.sh transaction_detail.java transaction_detail_visa_debit.java from transaction_detail_atm where posted_dte = current_date-1 and (1 = 0) 16/07/26 10:31:23 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select QueryResult.java sqoop_import_ALL.sh sqoop_import_ATM.sh sqoop_import_CC.sh sqoop_import_TD.sh sqoop_import_VD.sh testscript.sh transaction_detail.java transaction_detail_visa_debit.java from transaction_detail_atm where posted_dte = current_date-1 and (1 = 0) 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column DISPENSED_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column POSTED_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column POSTED_REF_CRNCY_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column UNCLEARED_1_DAY had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column UNCLEARED_3_DAY had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column UNCLEARED_4_DAY had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column UNCLEARED_5_DAY had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column UNCLEARED_6_DAY had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column UNCLEARED_TEMP had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column POSTED_DTE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column TRANS_DTE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column POSTED_COMMISSION_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column COMMISSION_REF_CRNCY had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column SEQUENCE_NO had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column TRACER_NO had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column FORCE_POST_RECVRY had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column FORCE_POST_RSN had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column CURR_LEDG_BAL had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column ATM_POSTED_DTE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column ACQUIRER_SETTLEMENT_DTE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column ISSUER_SETTLEMENT_DTE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column REQUESTED_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column ATM_DISPENSED_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column SETTLEMENT_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column CARD_EXCH_RTE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column SETTLEMENT_EXCH_RTE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column COMMISSION_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column ERR_INFO_CDE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column REVERSAL_RSN_CDE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column CARD_MBR_NO had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column SURCHARGE_DR_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column SURCHARGE_ORIG_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column ACQUIRER_SURCHARGE_AMT had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column ACQUIRER_INSTIT_ID had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 WARN hive.TableDefWriter: Column LOAD_DTE had to be cast to a less precise type in Hive 16/07/26 10:31:23 INFO hive.HiveImport: Loading uploaded data into Hive Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/iop/4.1.0.0/hive/lib/hive-common-1.2.1-IBM-12.jar!/hive-log4j.properties OK Time taken: 1.034 seconds OK Time taken: 0.15 seconds Loading data to table insights.transaction_detail_atm_archive chgrp: changing ownership of 'hdfs://rhdtmomg1.mid.aib.pri:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/insights.db/transaction_detail_atm_archive/part-m-00000_copy_5': User does not belong to hadoop Table insights.transaction_detail_atm_archive stats: [numFiles=6, numRows=0, totalSize=15088788330, rawDataSize=0] OK Time taken: 0.587 seconds
```

Comment: I assume that where you wrote `$OUTPUT | sed "s/'/\ /g"` you actually meant `echo $OUTPUT | sed "s/'/\ /g"` or something similar. (If yes, please [edit] your question to correct it.) The line starting with `[jar:file:...` isn't a shell command. If the script is short please add it to your question. If it's long please include a few lines above and below this offending line in your question, and _warn us_ that it's an extract.

Comment: Rather than remove offending quotes you should be able to double them up for the insert, which leaves them as single quotes in the stored data. `OUTPUT="$(...)"` and then `hive -e "INSERT INTO SCHEDULED_MIGRATION_LOGS VALUES ('${OUTPUT//\'/\'\'}')"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll edit my question shortly. Could you explain what the line `'${OUTPUT//\'/\'\'}'` does? I assume it escapes single quotes. Mine seems to be wiping the entire string so it's not working. Also, it seems the exclamation mark `!` is what might be causing issues

Comment: You're right in that it doubles up single quotes. Prepend `echo` to your `hive` command to see what the line does (i.e. `echo hive -e "INSERT...."`)

Comment: Also , to see what `$OUTPUT` contains, don't just `echo $OUTPUT` but quote the variable thus, `echo "$OUTPUT"` so that you get the newlines retained.

Comment: See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution

Answer (score 0):

In an SQL single-quoted string literal, you can include a single quote by doubling it. In bash, you can use the [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) feature `${VARIABLE//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` to get the value of `VARIABLE` with all occurrences of `PATTERN` replaced by `REPLACEMENT`.

```
hive -e "INSERT INTO SCHEDULED_MIGRATION_LOGS VALUES ('${OUTPUT//\'/\'\'}')"
```

Beware that if `OUTPUT` contains an invalid multibyte sequence followed by `'`, that `'` may be parsed as part of the invalid sequence, and the second `'` added by the doubling code would then end the string literal. This is hard to defend against unless you know how the database processes multibyte sequences. I don't know how this works in Apache Hive. If your data is supposed to be ASCII-only, you can check that it indeed contains only ASCII characters. The following snippet also rejects control characters.

```
LC_ALL=C
OUTPUT="$(…)"
case "$OUTPUT" in
  *[! -~]*) echo 1>&2 "Output contains characters that are not printable ASCII, aborting."; exit 3;;
esac
```